# Error with fileincluding

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a throughly thought out and comprehensive system to include pages for a small hobby project I kicked off today.

This is my code at the moment:

```
$page = get_uri(1);
if(!isset($page)){ $page = "Home"; }
$pages = array(
        "" => "home.php",
        "Home" => "home.php", 
        "Product" => "product.php",
        "category" => "category.php"
);
if(in_array($page, $pages) && file_exists(PAGE_DIR.$pages[$page])){
    include(PAGE_DIR.$pages[$page]);
} else {
    echo 'Uh oh. Four Oh Four, we failed to find the page you are looking for. :( <br />';
}
```

PAGE_DIR is defined to be `= "/pages/"`which is where I host my page files. I've created `Home.php` just to proove my theory, and `get_uri(1)` is, for now, a null value as I'm trying to get the theory to work. I'm sure the problem lies somewhere in `file_exists`, but cannot work out where the problem's at.

Answer (score 2):

`in_array` checks for the array *value*, not the key, which is what you want. Use `if (isset($pages[$page]) && ...)` instead.

Depending on your environment, the filenames may be case-sensitive. Create the file as home.php if you use lowercase filenames in your code.

Comment: Thanks alot, I was not aware that in_array didn't search through the keys, but now I know and I'm really happy to have gotten a small bit closer to being "pro" :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if the condition should be:

```
if(array_key_exists($page, $pages)  etc
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Use **[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)** instead of `in_array()`

Now your code will look like this.

```
$page = get_uri(1);
if(!isset($page)){ $page = "Home"; }
$pages = array(
        "" => "home.php",
        "Home" => "home.php", 
        "Product" => "product.php",
        "category" => "category.php"
);
if(array_key_exists($page, $pages) && file_exists(PAGE_DIR.$pages[$page])){
    include(PAGE_DIR.$pages[$page]);
} else {
    echo 'Uh oh. Four Oh Four, we failed to find the page you are looking for. :( <br />';
}
```